# How to use external libraries and headers in C Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries, external

I have a header file myheader.h and a static library libmylib.a file in directory1. In directory2, I'm writing a program which uses them. Suppose I have main.c in directory2 which uses myheader.h and libmylib.a. How do I create a Makefile to compile and link them?

Right now, in my main.c, I have added

```
#include "../directory1/myheader.h"
```

Here's my Makefile at the moment:

```
CC = gcc

INCLUDES = -I

CFLAGS = -g -Wall $(INCLUDES)

main: main.o ../directory1/libmylib.a
    $(CC) main.o ../directory1/libmylib.a -o main

main.o: main.c ../directory1/myheader.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c
```

I'm getting the following warning:

```
gcc -g -Wall -I -c main.c
/home/me/directory2/main.c:72: undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

where foo is one of the functions in the library.

Comment: I don't think the `-L` is helping.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the linking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. Fixed it.

I removed `#include "../directory1/myheader.h"` and replaced it with `#include "myheader.h"`.

Then in the Makefile, I used:

```
CC = gcc

INCLUDES = -I../directory1

CFLAGS = -g -Wall $(INCLUDES)

LDFLAGS = -L../directory1

main: main.o ../directory1/libmylib.a
    $(CC) main.o $(LDFLAGS) -lmylib -o main

main.o: main.c ../directory1/myheader.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `-lmylib` will be a problem. For non-static libraries you would need to fiddle with the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH; see [Why do I have to define LD_LIBRARY_PATH with an export every time I run my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695530/318716). You could fix your makefile by adding `-L ../directory1`. But the simplest thing is just replace `-lmylib` with `../directory1/libmylib.a`.

For example:

directory1/mylib.c

```
#include "../directory1/myheader.h"
void foo(void) {}
```

directory1/Makefile

```
libmylib.a: mylib.o
    ar r $@ $?
```

directory1/main.c:

```
#include "../directory1/myheader.h"
int main(void) {
   foo();
   return 0;
}
```

directory1/Makefile

```
main: main.o ../directory1/libmylib.a
   gcc main.o ../directory1/libmylib.a -o main
```

Comment: Made the changes. Added the warnings I'm getting to the question. Any advice?