# External library (CURL) in C makefile

Tags: curl, makefile, hyperlink, external

I want to show weather data on my Waveshare e-Paper display using an Raspberry Zero. Controlling the display works fine with the provided library. On the other hand I'm loading the weather data with a PHP script from a database. For this I'm using a HTTP-Post request with the CURL library. This works also fine.
Now I want to combine both "projects", so I included "curl/curl.h" to the exemplary Waveshare project but I get a "undefined reference error".
I know that some how a link to the CURL library is missing in the Makefile, but I never worked with Makefiles before. Currently I'm using the Makefile provided in the Waveshare library (https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper/blob/master/RaspberryPi_JetsonNano/c/Makefile).

I would be really happy for any support. I already tried hints from here ([How to use external libraries and headers in C Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045748/how-to-use-external-libraries-and-headers-in-c-makefile)), but I don't know how to adjust this for my makefile...

Thanks in advance
Andy

Answer (score 1):

curl needs to be linked to the executables in the recipes when compiling and linking. This is done by adding `-lcurl` to `gcc`'s arguments.

The makefile you linked to doesn't make use of `LDFLAGS` so there are a couple of options here:

1. When you run `make`, supply the linker option in `CFLAGS` like so: `CFLAGS="-lcurl" make`. This adds the appropriate linker argument for curl to the build commands in the Makefile
2. Modify the Makefile to include `-lcurl` where needed.

Option 1 requires no changes to the Makefile, but you'll have to remember to set the `CFLAGS` variable each time you run `make`. Option 2 requires changes to the Makefile but will then do the right thing when you run `make` on its own.