# Openblas: cblas.h is not found when using Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, blas, openblas

I encounter a problem when using cblas. I am new to use C++ to do numerics and I know Openblas is one of the famous library to perform linear algebra computation. I use  `brew install openblas` in my M1 Macbook. When the installation finishes, I follow the  [output instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBBkA.png)  by simply typing these commands in terminal. However, when I use the following example to test openblas,

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cblas.h"
#include "lapacke.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float b[] = {3, 1, 3, 1, 5};
    cblas_sasum(5, b, 1);
    cout << "Program finished";
}
```

Xcode says that `fatal error: 'cblas.h' file not found`. Therefore, I am wondering how to solve this issue. I appreciate any comment.

Comment: What is the command you use to compile? Can we see the full command? Probably you restarted the terminal after setting CPPFLAGS or for some reason the env variable is not read by the compiler.

Comment: Hi, @Fra93, I just type ```export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/lib"```  and ```export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/include"``` in terminal

Comment: What is then the command that you use for compilation? Also, is `cblas.h` present in the `/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/include`?

Comment: Suppose I save the above example as main.cpp , then I use ```g++ -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/include  main.cpp -o main``` in terminal. The output is ```Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_cblas_sasum", referenced from:
      _main in main-cf8342.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64```

Answer (score 0):

After several trial and error, I solve my problem by writing the following makefile:

```
CC = g++
INCLUDES = -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openblas/0.3.20/include
CPPFLAGS = -g -Wall $(INCLUDES)
LDFLAGS = -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/lib

all:main.o /opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/lib/libopenblas.a
        $(CC) main.o $(LDFLAGS) -lopenblas -o main.out

main.o:main.cpp /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openblas/0.3.20/include/cblas.h
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c main.cpp
clean:
        rm -f main.out
```

I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045748/how-to-use-external-libraries-and-headers-in-c-makefile) to write a makefile and it does work. To use Xcode to compile the `main.cpp` file, we need to add linker into Xcode. The instruction is discussed in this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7miwnp8iDm8)