# How to create a portable c++ based command line tool for Mac in Xcode 5?

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, xcode5

I'm having a really hard time with Xcode 5, of which there is very little easily accessible (easy to read and understand for someone with little knowledge of this stuff). I'm new to the platform, so don't assume I know anything.

I'm trying to create a c++ command line tool that is executable on a different machine. It works on my Mac, but not on my friend's. The target OS is OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion. It includes openCV libraries. Xcode seems to make a unix executable file (a binary file) that works perfectly on my computer, but comes up with library errors on other computers. how can I package my tool such that the dependencies are included in the final product?

I have searched through a lot of topics and most of it seems to be in older versions of Xcode.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel your pain.  The XCode doc is sorely lacking.  It's even hard to call it documenation.  Some things to look for: Where are the opencv libraries on your machine?  Are they on your friend's machine? Also, this article here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695530/why-do-i-have-to-define-ld-library-path-with-an-export-every-time-i-run-my-appli

Comment: hi you can try `otool -L` command on the executable to see the dependencies, another way is to statically link most dependencies

Comment: unfortunately you will need to be more specific... need some info from your friends machine... there is probably a dynamic linking issue, either you are linking to a dyld that you created and he doesn't have, or you have the deployment target set to too high of a version... I can't be more specific without a crash log.