# Cannot Open Shared Object file - C++ library in Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am trying to use a C++ compiled library in my Java code. I set `java.library.path` to `/usr/local/lib/` and I have all the `.so` files for the libraries installed there.

However, when I try to run the Java application I see the following:

```
Native code library failed to load. 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/lib/libA.so: libB.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However the file seems to be there:

```
ls /usr/local/lib/libB.so.2.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Jan 24 16:33 /usr/local/lib/libB.so.2.4 -> libB.so.2.4.5
```

The symlinked file also exists. Any idea why this library can't be found?

Comment: have you run `sudo ldconfig`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch just tried. It didn't help

Comment: Worth checking the file permissions.  Or you can use strace to see what it is trying to do.  You could also as a test System.load() the exact filename and see if/how that fails, possibly under strace again.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ok so I added `/usr/local/lib` to the `/etc/ld.so.conf` and then reran this and it seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: If someone could explain the details how this fixed the issue, I'd love to accept that answer

Comment: Did you try to replace the symbol name with the real file? `cp libB.so.2.4.5 libB.so.2.4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java was able to load the native code for library `A` (`libA.so`) and when it ran that native code there was a dependency on `libB.so` (however, it's in native code at that point - outside of the JVMs control). At that point, you must use the native libraries on the system. The usual mechanism is to set the [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695530/2970947) environment variable **or** use `ldconfig` (per the man page) which says in part

> ldconfig creates the necessary links  and  cache  to  the  most  recent
>         shared  libraries  found  in  the  directories specified on the command
>         line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/lib
>         and  /usr/lib).  The cache is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WebLogic: make sure you have a system variable called `USTART_LD_LIB` in the `wlstart`-script of weblogic that overwrites `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. So you need to set this variable also append the lib to this variable and also simultaneously set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

The reason is you cannot keep on exporting the variables before start of your app manually..