# Error while loading shared libraries in linux; using docker and python

Tags: linux, docker, shared-libraries

I am trying to run an executable on a linux machine that I made in a linux virtual machine on my mac. To download the program and all the corresponding dependencies etc. I am using Docker. To execute the program I am running a python2.7 script.

Every time I try to run the program, `emotion-processing`, I get the following error:

```
emotion-processing: error while loading shared libraries: libaffdex-native.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I set everything up in my Docker .worker file as so:

```
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libopencv-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev uuid-dev
RUN mkdir $HOME/affdex-sdk
RUN wget https://download.affectiva.com/linux/affdex-cpp-sdk-3.2-20-ubuntu-xenial-xerus-64bit.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzvf affdex-cpp-sdk-3.2-20-ubuntu-xenial-xerus-64bit.tar.gz -C $HOME/affdex-sdk
RUN wget https://github.com/path/to/emotion-processing?raw=true
RUN mv emotion-processing?raw=true /usr/local/bin/emotion-processing
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/emotion-processing
```

I then set an environment variable to the grandparent folder of the missing library.

```
ENV AFFECTIVA_SDK_FOLDER="$HOME/affdex-sdk"
```

After that, in my a python2.7 file, I concatenate `"/lib"` onto `AFFECTIVA_SDK_FOLDER`.

```
affdex_sdk_lib_folder = os.environ.get("AFFECTIVA_SDK_FOLDER") + "/lib"
```

Then, I tell the program where the library is right before execution.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/affdex-sdk/lib" emotion-processing
```

I got this idea by looking at [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695530/why-do-i-have-to-define-ld-library-path-with-an-export-every-time-i-run-my-appli/695539#695539). But alas, setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in any number of ways doesn't seem to work. I have been looking at other posts on here, but nothing seems to solve the problem. I am trying to avoid recompilation.

Thank you in advance for your thoughts and advice.

Comment: can you post your Dockerfile? You should replace all your `RUN` by only one, with `&&` for chaining commands

Comment: Would this change the actual outcome of a non-located library? Or, is this more of a style comment?

Comment: This also makes it very hard to debug. Thus, keeping the lines as RUN would be preferable.